# How to broadcast numpy indexing along batch dimensions?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, array-broadcasting, matrix-indexing

For example, `np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])[np.triu_indices(2)]` has shape `(3,)`, being a flattened list of the upper triangular entries.  However, if I have a batch of 2x2 matrices:

```
foo = np.repeat(np.array([[[1,2],[3,4]]]), 30, axis=0)
```

and I want to obtain the upper triangular indices of each matrix, the naive thing to try would be:

```
foo[:,np.triu_indices(2)]
```

However, this object is actually of shape `(30,2,3,2)` (as opposed to `(30,3)` that we might expect if we had extracted the upper triangular entries batch-wise.

How can we broadcast tuple indexing along the batch dimensions?

Comment: What do you mean by "of each matrix" precisely? You only have one matrix which is not even square shaped! If you want the upper triangle of each 2x2 sub array (axes 1 and 2) you can do `x, y = np.triu_indices(2); foo[:,x,y]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get the tuples and use those to index into the last two dims -

```
r,c = np.triu_indices(2)
out = foo[:,r,c]
```

Alternatively, one-liner with `Ellipsis` that works for both `3D` and `2D` arrays -

```
foo[(Ellipsis,)+np.triu_indices(2)]
```

It will work for `2D` arrays similarly -

```
out = foo[r,c] # foo as 2D input array
```

---

### Masking way

**3D array case**

We can also use a mask for a `masking` based way -

```
foo[:,~np.tri(2,k=-1, dtype=bool)]
```

**2D array case**

```
foo[~np.tri(2,k=-1, dtype=bool)]
```

Comment: Seems like we can't directly unpack & index them at the same time.. Else it'd be just a single step, for dimensions > 2.

Comment: @kmario23 There's one with `Ellipsis`.

Comment: Jaaa, danke!! To make it less cryptic, we could also write: `foo[(..., *np.triu_indices(2))]`

Comment: @kmario23 Yup, that works too. Note that it's specific to Python 3.x. Thanks.